# App is not able to be installed properly on X, XR via Adhoc using diawi.com

Tags: ios, adhoc

iOS app is not able to be executed on iPhone X, XR device via Adhoc using diawi.com URL.

On some device, app is installed properly and excuted well, but on other device like Xs and XR, it couldn't be executed.

It seemed installed, but app icon looks dark like meaning it can't be executed.

[image: Screenshot]

I added all device UDID like below.(some characters changed for security)

c5345ca83a57f9e9384e852dd3td401de3c232a0 (iPhone 7)
00003010-00324C483452002E (iPhone X)

And I created provisioning profile for adhoc, so on some device it works correctly.

I want to know why other device can't execute app.

you can see the result in screenshot

Comment: You can verify the embedded provisioning profile of adhoc ipa by seeing its package content and open that profile in textedit and search for your device UDID.

Comment: @Mahendra you mean some plist files?

Comment: @Mahendra I can find UDIDs in provisioning file. As I wrote, I enrolled all UDIDs correctly..

Comment: @Kazaka just delete your installed adhoc profile and reinstall it and then regenerate the iPA and before installation , restart your device and check if pervious application is visible then delete it & proceed for installation

Comment: I have faced similar issue what I was doing is I was creating ipa by selecting a specific device. When I have selected `Generic iOS Device` option and archived it, it was correctly installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the similar problem.

The thing that was troubling me is When I archived ipa at that time I'd selected my iPhone 6s+. SO when I gave it to client he was nota able to install app even though I have added his UDID in provisioning profile.

> Then I've created ipa by selecting generic iOS device and client installed app on his device iPhone XR so It was installed successfully.

[image]